# Error: expected expression before ‘{’ token

Tags: c

I've tried to find this online, but all the other questions are about code that is nothing related to what I'm looking for. I'm trying to see if I can have multiple executing lines in a ternary operator:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i == 1;
    i = 1?{printf("H");printf("J")}:printf("H");
}
```

The output of this is the error:

```
Error: expected expression before ‘{’ token
```

What is wrong here to cause that?

Comment: The "ternary" conditional expression is an expression, and all parts of it must be expressions. You cant have general statements anywhere in it. And I hope you *never* write code like this other than for curiosity. It's bad and unreadable and therefore almost unmaintainable.

Comment: This spam code, it's just for testing out new functions and things from a language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to see if I can have multiple executing lines in a ternary operator

You can, using a comma operator

```
i = 1?printf("H"),printf("J"):printf("H");
```

Comment: Yeah this does work. But implementing this to my real code made it come out with a type mismatch. So ultimately I'm scraping the `?:` operator

Answer (score 0):

you can replace your line with:

```
printf(i==1? "HJ" : "H");
```

Comment: Yes, that would make the program work, I should've specified that this was just an example of what I wanted to do. I didn't include my code because I wanted to configure it myself, not have someone else do my work for me.